# Webpack 5 in Ceate React App can't resolve not fully specified routes

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, webpack-5

We are developing a react library and recently noticed, that it throws an error when we want to consume it with a new (webpack 5) Create React App.
It complains about this:

"BREAKING CHANGE: The request failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified (probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '.mjs' file, or a '.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"')."

I managed to fix this, by adding

```
{
    test: /\.m?js/,
    resolve: {
      fullySpecified: false,
    },
}
```

While this works fine for any applications that have access to the webpack config, we'd like to make our lib "plug&play", without any eject or additional setup.
What config should we have to make the consumer's webpack resolve our not fully specified routes?
[Code on github](https://github.com/instructure/instructure-ui)

Comment: `I managed to fix this, by adding` are you saying that you ejected your CRA project and added that to the webpack config?

Comment: Any follow up on this?

Comment: Related GH issue for this error? https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/issues/200. Also [Webpack docs for `fullySpecified: false`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#resolvefullyspecified).

Answer (score 21):

I solved this without ejecting or modifying files in node_modules. First, add craco to override the webpack config: `yarn add -D @craco/craco`. Next, in the root of your project (where `package.json` is located) create a file named `craco.config.js` with the following content:

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        configure: {
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                        test: /\.m?js$/,
                        resolve: {
                            fullySpecified: false,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        },
    },
};
```

This config disables the breaking change that causes this error. Then change the start/build/test commands in `package.json` replacing `react-scripts` to `craco`:

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "craco start",
        "build": "craco build",
        "test": "craco test",
```

Now do the usual `yarn start` and it should work.

Comment: This solved my issue! I did see a similar answer elsewhere on the internet but their craco config was incorrectly formatted it seems. This is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @user3130985 Hopefully the answer is helpful. Thoroughly answering questions is time-consuming. If your question is **solved**, please _**accept** the solution_. The **✔** is below the **▲/▼** arrow, at the top left of the answer. A new solution can be accepted if a better one shows up. You may also vote on the usefulness of an answer with the **▲/▼** arrow, if you have a 15+ reputation. **Leave a comment if a solution doesn't answer the question.** [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thank you.