# embedding flowise AI chatbot into my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, embed, chatbot, flowise

Hello everyone im trying to embedd a chat bot into my app the following way:

```
import { BubbleChat } from 'flowise-embed-react'

const Chatbot = () => {
    return (
        <BubbleChat chatflowid="099e38db-3758-4427-a89f-8fd9f450b59c" apiHost="http://localhost:3000" />
    );
};


return (    <Chatbot /> )
```

that is the gist of what i added to my react app (in the navbar component for now just to see it working)  and im getting the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'flowise-embed/dist/web' in 'C:\Pangea-Projects\InsightsSolution\node_modules\flowise-embed-react\dist'
Did you mean 'web.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request 'flowise-embed/dist/web' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
```

the docs of this library are pretty much non existent, does anyone have an idea for a fix?

Comment: I know it's a few months later, but why are you `return (    <Chatbot /> )` - shouldn't you `export { Chatbot }`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done:
`npm install flowise-embed`

and make sure you got this:

`import { BubbleChat } from 'flowise-embed-react';`

Comment: yes i did. also the import is the same

Comment: no, i installed the libraries and the import was correct before positng the question.

Answer (score 0):

there is a bug with create react app (or error i suppose).  either way, the solution comes from the Flowise github issue page:  https://github.com/FlowiseAI/Flowise/issues/825

solution from HenryHengZJ:

> That's a known error with CRA (facebook/create-react-app#11865).
>
> This fixes the issue:
> [Webpack 5 in Ceate React App can't resolve not fully specified routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70964723/webpack-5-in-ceate-react-app-cant-resolve-not-fully-specified-routes/75109686#75109686)
>
> Basically, you have to use craco yarn add -D @craco/craco

the linked fix by rkfg is as follows:

> I solved this without ejecting or modifying files in node_modules.
> First, add craco to override the webpack config: yarn add -D
> @craco/craco. Next, in the root of your project (where package.json is
> located) create a file named craco.config.js with the following
> content:
>
> module.exports = {
> webpack: {
> configure: {
> module: {
> rules: [
> {
> test: /.m?js$/,
> resolve: {
> fullySpecified: false,
> },
> },
> ],
> },
> },
> }, }; This config disables the breaking change that causes this error. Then change the start/build/test commands in package.json
> replacing react-scripts to craco:
>
> "scripts": {
> "start": "craco start",
> "build": "craco build",
> "test": "craco test", Now do the usual yarn start and it should work.